# Ubuntu Live 12.04.3 x64 Skip installation screen

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

My laptop's internal HDD broke a week ago and now it won't boot (or do anything) from it. So I made a Live stick since I only use the computer for surfing and watching BluRay. Note: The stick has been created with Linux Live USB Creator, inclusive persistent mode so I can customize the Live stick.

Everything is fine except at the start of Ubuntu when there pops up a window "install" with two buttons "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". When I close it or click on Try, nothing happens for 1 minute and then the Desktop appears.

It's really annoying when the screen comes up after 10 seconds and then needs another 50 or so... (How) Can that be skipped?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a Computer (let say we use Windows) and a Text editor (here i use Notepad++)

1 Browse your LiveUSB and find folder name *isolinux* or *syslinux*

2 Find file named *sysylinux.cfg* or *isolinux.cfg* create a backup of it,and open it on the ext editor

3 Copy this code in to it (you can modify it as you like but becareful)

```
default live
label live
  say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
```

4 Save it,and reboot.If something happen when booting you already have the backup.